# Datagridview export to excel not working

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I would like to ask how come my export to excel code isn't working. I have this code in my toolstripmenu click.

```
private void excelFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arrays = new string[this.dgvResult.Columns.Count];
    int icol = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridColum in this.dgvResult.Columns)
    {
        //for (irow = 0; irow <= this.dgvResult.Columns.Count - 1; irow++)
        //{

        arrays[icol] = this.dgvResult.Columns[icol].Name;
        icol++;
        // }
    }
    SystemUtil.ExportToExel_DG(dgvResult, arrays, "", "");
}
```

I have this code in this class to to export my datagridview items into excel

```
public void ExportToExel_DG(DataGridView dg, string[] arrays,string sTitle,string sRundate)
{
    try
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        //Excel.Range oRange;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        // Set some properties 
        oXL.Visible = true;
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

        // Get a new workbook. 
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);

        // Get the active sheet 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Name = "Attachment";


        //Title
        //oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Corporate Name:" + sTitle;
        //oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Utilization Reports";
        //oSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Run Date: "  + sRundate;


        int rowCount = 1;
        int RecNo = 1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dg.Rows)
        {
            int iCell = 2;
            rowCount += 1;

            for (int i = 1; i <= dg.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                if (rowCount == 1)
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Record No.";
                    oSheet.Cells[1, iCell] = arrays[i - 1];// dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                }                        
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = RecNo;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, iCell] = dgr.Cells[i - 1].Value.ToString();

                iCell++;
            }
            RecNo++;
        }

        oSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 2] = "TOTAL";


        oSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        oSheet = null;

        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Every time I click the tool strip menu to export to excel, a blank excel workbook pops up, the items that I want to export from my data grid view wasn't there. I am new in making c# applications.

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch. It is hiding problems from you, not fixing problems You should also get rid of all that `GC` stuff. If you're new at this, then you can have no idea at all what that code is doing.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've removed the try/catch, there is no error but the workbook the pops up is still blank.

Comment: Good. Now you know that there _are_ no errors. Before, there could have been errors but you wouldn't have known.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you have any solution in this problem? I don't get it, why is the data on my data grid view not appearing on the workbook that loaded.

Comment: My solution would be to debug through the code. For instance, I'd make sure that both loops really execute. I'd make sure of what data I'm putting into the Cells. I also question why you're getting rid of the workbook before you can see whether you have data in it. What happens if you get rid of `oSheet = null` in addition to getting rid of the `GC` code like I asked?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, I got rid all of the GC code, I also removed the oSheet = null, I think I have a problem on the loop in my class, I've debugged it, the workbook pops up before getting into the loop in my class. And rowCount == 1 is always false.

Comment: Yeah, debugging it would be the thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Again the issue is with:

// Get the active sheet 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Name = "Attachment";

You can not use the Workbook interface to assign ActiveSheet to a variable you have to use the application interface...

Chang it to:

// Get the active sheet 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oXL.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Name = "Attachment";

Further explanation: MSDN provides the following note regarding the Workbook Interface....

"This interface is implemented by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime. It is not intended to be implemented in your code. For more information, see Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime Overview."